# Reverse polarity protection with a MOSFET, am I doing it right?

Tags: mosfet, schematics, lithium-ion, charger, reverse-polarity

I'm creating a simple LiPo charger and I would like to add a reverse polarity function to the module.
The source voltage is **4.2V**, the maximum current draw is **2A**.

Is this schematic correct?

The MOSFET used in the schematic is **IRLML5203TRPBF**.

Also, how can I determine the correct MOSFET (Vds, Vdg, etc..) for my project?
I choose this one because of it's maximum current capabilities. (Vdss -30V 165@VGS = -4.5V -2.6A)
[image: Reverse polarity protection schematic sample]

Comment: Your FET will only be partially turned on at 4.2V, and you have to remember that the charger could start at about 2.5 or 3V depending on how deeply discharged the battery is.  Take a look at a logic level PFET like the Si1401.  The general structure of your circuit is correct, the PFET will be turned on and will not rely on the body diode.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. How can you tell that my FET will be only partially turned on? What data do I have to look for in the datasheets? The main goal was to protect the battery from shorting out and/or blowing up the charger (which is a TP5100 module).

Comment: Add a resistor and a zener diode:    https://components101.com/articles/design-guide-pmos-mosfet-for-reverse-voltage-polarity-protection

Comment: @ryzen Can you clarify which device are you expecting to have a possibility of being plugged in backwards?  The charger or the battery?  Or both?

Comment: @Vinzent an IRLML5203 is a P-Channel device not an N, and the OP has used the appropriate schematic symbol too.

Comment: @SteKulov Only the battery can be plugged in backwards.

Comment: @ryzen In that case, I think your whole logic here flawed.  Please check this link for more information:  http://blog.deconinck.info/post/2017/12/22/18650-Battery-charger-reverse-polarity-protection